# Can i customise iOS native Calendar?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios10

1. I want to modify UI, like i want to add some event to particular date.
2. I want to perform some action like Holidays button which will open some having displaying upcoming holiday?

Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: you can add events which will automatically shown by iOS in calendar but you can not modify iOS calendar... its restricted.

Comment: If you want to accomplish this, you will have to build your own calendar. This is lots of work, but is definitely possible. Or, you can use a calendar that others have developed and customize it to your own needs.